# Creating a copy of CiviCRM on a test sub-domain (Wordpress)

Tags: testing

I need simple step-by-step procedure to copy my current production site to a sub-domain on the same server, that we intend using for testing/development (its important that we retain all our custom fields and other customization). We are running Wordpress, CiviCRM 4.7.12.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) for this.

Comment: I have looked at "Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location", but some steps need some clarification for me. For example: Step 4b(iii) states "If you are using a fresh install you need to make sure that the new version matches the version of your database.
Check in your live database "SELECT version FROM civicrm_domain" or check this value in the SQL export file you are using to move the database". Are they talking about the version of CiviCRM here, or the CMS or SQL?I was looking for something that just explains what to do for Wordpress CMS.

Comment: The query returns the installed version of CiviCRM. Beyond that, I'd suggest you try the migration and see what happens. You'll learn more from trying than from expecting a guide for your particular circumstances.